# Spring boot and react application on the same port error finding index.js

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, artifact, yarn-v2

I followed this tutorial to initialize react and spring boot application on the same port: so that when I launch my spring boot application I can view the site from localhost:8080

Tutorial: https://medium.com/codex/run-react-frontend-and-springboot-backend-on-the-same-port-and-package-them-as-a-single-artifact-a790c9e10ac1

The problem is that when I go to localhost:8080, I get a whitelabel error page (HTTP 403).
**This is the structure of my project:**

[image: 1]

I noticed that if I move all the packages except the main of the application, under com.websitePetcare, I can view the site on localhost:8080 but not all my Restcontrollers are found and I can’t access the Apis.
How can I keep the project structure so (because it works) and display the site on localhost:8080?

**WebSecurity configuration under config package:**

```
package com.websitePetcare.Petcare.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import com.websitePetcare.Petcare.services.AuthenticationFilter;
import com.websitePetcare.Petcare.services.LoginFilter;
import com.websitePetcare.Petcare.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl;

import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl customUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PUT","OPTIONS","PATCH", "DELETE"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));
        http.csrf().disable().cors().configurationSource(request -> corsConfiguration).and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/users/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/users/create").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(new LoginFilter("/api/v1/users/login", authenticationManager()),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

**UsersController under the package controllers:**

```
package com.websitePetcare.Petcare.controllers;

import com.websitePetcare.Petcare.repositories.UserRepository;
import com.websitePetcare.Petcare.models.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
public class UsersController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView home() {
        ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("index");
        return mav;
    }

    @GetMapping("/users")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<User> list() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping(value="/users/create")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void create(@RequestBody User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

**PetcareApplication main:**

```
package com.websitePetcare.Petcare;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class PetcareApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PetcareApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.websitePetcare</groupId>
    <artifactId>Petcare</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Petcare</name>
    <description>Backend and Frontend for Petcare Website</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <frontend-src-dir>${project.basedir}/src/main/frontend</frontend-src-dir>
        <node.version>v16.13.0</node.version>
        <yarn.version>v1.22.17</yarn.version>
        <frontend-maven-plugin.version>1.12.0</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>

                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                    <yarnVersion>${yarn.version}</yarnVersion>
                    <workingDirectory>${frontend-src-dir}</workingDirectory>
                    <installDirectory>${project.build.directory}</installDirectory>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install-frontend-tools</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>yarn-install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>build-frontend</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>yarn</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>position-react-build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/static</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${frontend-src-dir}/build</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/websitepetcare
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=*******
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true

# Because detection is disabled you have to set correct dialect by hand.
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.thymeleaf.prefix=file:///${user.dir}/target/classes/static/
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to create the build package of your frontend first and put it under your resources folder. Basically in your resources package you can have static folder and but your frontend build outcome there. And I noticed that this is also explained in the tutorial you are using:
I can suggest using `frontend-maven-plugin` for build of frontend packages:

```
              <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>v12.12.0</nodeVersion>
                    <npmVersion>6.9.0</npmVersion>
                    <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/frontend</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

and `maven-resources-plugin` or `maven-antrun-plugin` to copy resources in your static folder.

```
             <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <copy todir="${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/static">
                                    <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/src/main/frontend/build"/>
                                </copy>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

You might need to add a resource handler like the following:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
      registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
          .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
          .resourceChain(true)
          .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
            @Override
            protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath,
                                           Resource location) throws IOException {
              Resource requestedResource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);
              return requestedResource.exists() && requestedResource.isReadable()
                  ? requestedResource
                  : new ClassPathResource("/static/index.html");
            }
          });
    }
```

I hope this helps :))

Answer (score 0):

Don't use same port number to both frontend and backend, By default spring-boot takes port 8080 or you can change the default port of spring, you can modify the application.properties file.

```
server.port=8081
```

(or)

I think you have to check once again @CrossOrigin URL that you have given your URL of Spring-Application but actually you will give the URL of your React application. Please check it and run.
Ignore this message if I am wrong.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it's not correct. I want to run backend and frontend on the same port. The problem is that when i open localhost:8080 i can't see my frontend (but the backend with postman works) and i see a whitelabel error page.

Comment: Please make sure your URL is http://localhost:8080/api/v1, is it right? or something else? for react home page that is here index page.

Comment: localhost:8080/api/v1 is for the backend API. If i open it, i see a whitelabel error page. I must see the index page when i open localhost:8080 and that is possible with thymeleaf plugin who copy the build of the frontend in the target/classes of the backend. For example, if i move all the packages (not the main) outside the package com.websitePetcare.Petcare to com.websitePetcare, i can see my frontend but the backend will not work anymore.